# Prevent application crash on completion of Reward Ad - Google Admob

Tags: java, android, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I am using Google Admob to display Reward Ad.

Following are the details :

Dependency : **'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'**

Version Info In build.gradle :

```
compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 28
```

Manifest File Test Credential:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
           android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" />
```

Initialization Code :

```
private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
    rewardAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}

private void initializeAd(){
    rewardAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    rewardAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
    loadRewardedVideoAd();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    loadRewardedVideoAd();
}
```

RewardedAd is working fine in Devices With **Android API 25 and above**.

But when RewardedAd is displayed on devices with **API Level less than 25** ,
application crashes on RewardedAd start.
Activities **onStop** method is called while the RewardedAd is still running.

I have tested in Emulator as well as Real Devices

Following are the logs:

```
  Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 280
W/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version < 2, falling back to loadModule2
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000001/n/x86
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
W/Ads: #007 Could not call remote method. @28
   com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbah: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: Failed to instantiate module class: com.google.android.gms.ads.measurement.DynamiteMeasurementManager
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbaf.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzamj.zzc(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzamk.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    Caused by: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: Failed to instantiate module class: com.google.android.gms.ads.measurement.DynamiteMeasurementManager
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.instantiate(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbaf.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzamj.zzc(Unknown Source) 
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzamk.run(Unknown Source) 
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.measurement.DynamiteMeasurementManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000001/DynamiteModulesA_GmsCore_prodmnc_alldpi_release.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000001/n/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
       at ae.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):6)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.instantiate(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbaf.zza(Unknown Source) 
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzamj.zzc(Unknown Source) 
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzamk.run(Unknown Source) 
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
       Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.measurement.DynamiteMeasurementManager
       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
       at af.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):123)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
               ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
V/FA: onActivityCreated
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
   Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.webview version 44.0.2403.119 (code 246011910)
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/webview/lib/x86
I/LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 2 ms (timestamps 7846-7848)
   Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider: Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {d1ec7ac}
I/LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(120)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I/BrowserStartupController: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
E/SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
W/chromium: [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(285)] locale_file_path.empty()
E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
   validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb30527c0, tid 15986
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xb30588e0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb30588e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0b56b60)
E/DataReductionProxySettingListener: No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
W/AudioManagerAndroid: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
   Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
E/Ads: Google Mobile Ads SDK initialization functionality unavailable for this session. Ad requests can be made at any time.
I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8495329704522213759}]
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
W/chromium: [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_config.cc(423)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
   Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 8228058
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9d27e440, tid 16041
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4627(447KB) AllocSpace objects, 7(140KB) LOS objects, 22% free, 2MB/3MB, paused 6.786ms total 23.801ms
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9d27e240, tid 16039
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9d243860: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9d242060: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d242060: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b250)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d243860: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b7c0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d243860: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b7c0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9d244100: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d244100: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b250)
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
W/BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 15986
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 8229065
D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=1007, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8495329704522213759}]
V/FA: onActivityCreated
I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
D/FA: Logging event (FE): _vs, Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-8495329704522213759, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=HomeActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8495329704522213754}]
D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 8229219
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9449(602KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(632KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 4MB/7MB, paused 10.490ms total 55.511ms
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d243860: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b7c0)
W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x9aeb58c0
W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
D/FA: Logging event (FE): _aq, Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=HomeActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8495329704522213754, ad_event_id(_aeid)=-8495329704522213755}]
W/AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
   Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
   Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9a22ec80: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9a22ec80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b250)
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9a22ed40: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9a22ed40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b250)
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9a23bde0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9a23bde0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b250)
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9a23bfc0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9a23bfc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b250)
W/BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 15986
W/BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 15986
I/ExoPlayerImpl: Init 1.3.1
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/0 for video/mpeg2
   Unrecognized profile/level 0/2 for video/mpeg2
   Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
I/SoftAAC2: limiting to stereo output
I/SoftAAC2: Reconfiguring decoder: 0->44100 Hz, 0->2 channels
D/FA: Setting user property (FE): _sid
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
D/FA: Logging event (FE): _s, Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=HomeActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8495329704522213754}]
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 11137
   Connection attempt already in progress
   Activity paused, time: 8240277
D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_impression(_ai), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, ad_event_id(_aeid)=-8495329704522213735}]
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=HomeActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-8495329704522213754, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=AdActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8495329704522213734}]
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
   Activity resumed, time: 8240341
D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=11137, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=HomeActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8495329704522213754}]
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d243860: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b7c0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9a23bde0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b250)
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 18019(1263KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(100KB) LOS objects, 22% free, 5MB/7MB, paused 9.166ms total 29.630ms
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9a23bfc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b250)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d243860: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b7c0)
I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9a23bde0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b250)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d243860: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b7c0)
D/SoftAVCDec: Number of CPU cores: 4
I/MediaCodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] setting surface generation to 16369665
W/OMXNodeInstance: [1:google.h264.decoder] component does not support metadata mode; using fallback
E/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -1010
D/SoftAVCDec: Number of CPU cores: 4
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d243860: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b7c0)
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 7
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9d27e200, tid 16140
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d243860: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b7c0)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d243860: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b7c0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d243860: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b7c0)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d243860: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b7c0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d243860: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b7c0)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d243860: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b7c0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d243860: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b7c0)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d243860: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b7c0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d243860: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b7c0)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d243860: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b7c0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d243860: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b7c0)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x9aeb7940
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ai, Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=AdActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8495329704522213734, ad_event_id(_aeid)=-8495329704522213723}]
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ar, Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, ad_unit_id(_ai)=ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=AdActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8495329704522213734, type=coins, ad_event_id(_aeid)=-8495329704522213721, value=10}]
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9a23bfc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b250)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
D/FA: Logging event (FE): _xu, Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, ad_unit_id(_ai)=ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=AdActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-8495329704522213734, exposure_time(_xt)=9614}]
W/Ads: #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
   #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
W/Ads: #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
   #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
W/Ads: #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
   #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
W/BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 15986
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d243860: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d87b7c0)
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb403dca0
W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.os.Handler) {cbeaedc} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {cbeaedc} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
       at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:543)
       at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
       at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
       at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
       at android.os.Handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(Handler.java:534)
       at android.os.Handler.sendEmptyMessage(Handler.java:519)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzgk.stop(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzgi.stop(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbdr.stop(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbcr.destroy(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbcx.onDestroy(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbhl.zzaao(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbhb.onPageFinished(Unknown Source)
       at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onPageFinished(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:560)
       at org.chromium.android_webview.AwWebContentsObserver.didFinishLoad(AwWebContentsObserver.java:44)
       at org.chromium.content.browser.webcontents.WebContentsObserverProxy.didFinishLoad(WebContentsObserverProxy.java:162)
       at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
       at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:53)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
W/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Sent message(1) after release. Message ignored.
W/ScreenOrientationListener: Removing an inexistent observer!
```

How can I avoid such crashes in Android Devices below **API 25** as it is working fine in **API 25 and above** ?